# Listview : How do I get RowHeader

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView whose size is fixed to maximum of 10 items

View Property is set to List and scroll is disabled

I want to get row headers numbered from 1 to 10

How do I get that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void InitializeListView()
{
ColumnHeader header1 = this.listView1.InsertColumn(0, "Name", 10*listView1.Font.SizeInPoints.ToInt32() , HorizontalAlignment.Center);
ColumnHeader header2 = this.listView1.InsertColumn(1, "E-mail", 20*listView1.Font.SizeInPoints.ToInt32(), HorizontalAlignment.Center);
ColumnHeader header3 = this.listView1.InsertColumn(2, "Phone", 20*listView1.Font.SizeInPoints.ToInt32(), HorizontalAlignment.Center );
}
```

source:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/ListViewInCSharp11172005021741AM/ListViewInCSharp.aspx